# OCaml empty global variable

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to know how do I define an empty! global variable of type `Hashtbl` in OCaml?
I don't want to use `Hashtbl.create` because I don't know its initial size and I don't want to guess the initial size for performance reasons.

Basically this `Hashtbl` variable will be assigned a real `Hashtbl` in a function and then this variable will be shared among other functions so I don't want to pass it around as an argument all the time hence I'd like it to be global.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask for is possible. You can define a global reference (this lets you assign it later on) to a hash table option (this lets you leave it uninitialized at first). The definition will look like this:

```
let hashtable = ref None
```

The initialization will be:

```
hashtable := Some (Hashtbl.create n)
```

To use it, you will also have to explain what should happen if you haven't initialized it yet:

```
match !hashtable with 
  | None -> assert false
  | Some h -> frobnicate h
```

In practice, uninitialized variables are against the OCaml philosophy and will only make your life harder. I strongly advise you not to use this approach. My two suggestions would be:

- Determine the performance loss caused by creating a hash table with a guessed size. The overhead might be much smaller than you think.
- Just pass the hash table everywhere. It's a single argument, which is shorter than an option reference...
- Put your hash table and the functions using it in a class.

Answer (score 7):

Hashtables in OCaml grow as needed, so you can just give a g best guess at first, for example :

```
module A

let hash = Hashtbl.create 123;;

...

let exceed_hash () = 
  for i = 1 to 555 do 
    Hashtbl.add hash i (string_of_int i) 
  done;;
```

Although you exceed the initial number but it will work smoothly too, check this tutorial for more info http://www.ocaml-tutorial.org/hashtbl